# Search/Find within a List of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and I'm trying to search or address data within the lists.

E.g.

```
print(data[0])
print(data[12])
```

Gives me

```
['Spinward-Rimward', 'Sol', 0, 0, 'N/A', '']
['Spinward-Rimward', 'POL-6387', 2, -8, 'TWE', 'Atol']
```

And

```
print(data[0][0])
```

gives me

```
Spinward-Rimward
```

And I can get an individual item

```
index = data[0].index('Sol')
print(index)
```

Gets me

```
1
```

But searching within the lists of lists is boggling me. I have a few hundred lines of data and if I wanted every row that contained Spinward-Rimward or every row where Latitude and Longtitude were less than 10, I'm pretty stumped.

I need this because I plan to be running arithmetic operations on the Lat/Long when people enter the name of the Star System to find the distance between two stars.

tl;dr - I'm a python noob who is in lockdown and decided to make a fun toy for players of the Alien RPG which has a 2d map of 3D space.

Comment: what do you want to find?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource.  You haven't asked a question, but you seem to be casting about for a general understanding of how to manipulate large amounts of data.  You need to keep learning your language capabilities: program controls, data structures and abstractions, etc.

Comment: As your data seems to be structured, I suggest you using and learning ´pandas´, it is speacially designed for these type of jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I wanted every row that contained Spinward-Rimward or every row where Latitude and Longtitude were less than 10

The first is pretty straightforward, you already know the answer:

```
for item in data:
    if item[0] == 'Spinward-Rimward':
        print(item)
```

For the second, you will find tuple unpack to be convenient:

```
for spin, star, lat, lng, *_ in data:
    if lat <= 10 and lng <= 10:
        print(item)
```

That `*` star syntax means "gimme the rest" as a list,
and using `_` underscore as a variable name is a conventional way of saying
"I won't use this value so I won't even bother giving it a real name."
For extra credit we could use that syntax
to modify the answer to your first question:

```
for spin, *rest in data:
    if spin == 'Spinward-Rimward':
        print(rest)
```

Comment: Fabulous - didn't even occur to me to use a for loop. Thank you so much. My experience of python is approximately 8 hours. 

Thank you for being understanding.